# Issue with void paint() after upgrading flutter version from 3.0.5 to 3.10.6

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my source code

```
void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2,
  })
```

This is the error

```
'GradientsRectSliderTrackShape.paint' ('void Function(PaintingContext, Offset, {double additionalActiveTrackHeight, required Animation<double> enableAnimation, bool isDiscrete, bool isEnabled, required RenderBox parentBox, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required Offset thumbCenter})') isn't a valid override of 'SliderTrackShape.paint' ('void Function(PaintingContext, Offset, {required Animation<double> enableAnimation, bool isDiscrete, bool isEnabled, required RenderBox parentBox, Offset? secondaryOffset, required SliderThemeData sliderTheme, required TextDirection textDirection, required Offset thumbCenter})').dartinvalid_override
slider_theme.dart(1090, 8): The member being overridden.
```

It is an internal file so I'm not sure what to do and I'm not sure what exactly has deprecatedy.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing some added parameters to the original paint().

Here is what I see in slider_theme.dart. Make sure you have all the needed parameters.

```
void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,   });
```

I ran into this issue for a different reason however. My TextDirection was defined in Material as well as another package I was importing. The below code was the fix (thanks to  https://community.flutterflow.io/custom-code/post/custom-widget-error-isn-t-a-valid-override-of-slidercomponentshape-paint-U7D6ClG002bWOWr)

```
+++ import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as Material; 

...

--- required TextDirection textDirection,

+++ required Material.TextDirection textDirection,
```